# Resource recommendation on Probability, Combinatorics, and Statistics.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, book-recommendation, online-resources

Introductory and Intuitive book covering Probability, Combinatorics, and Statistics.

Some books that are "Introductory and Intuitive" have read in the past are Calculus Made Easy by  Silvanus P. Thompson, Div Grad Curl and All that by H M Schey and Differential Equations by Shepley Ross. Any book written in the ease and clarity, on the topics mentioned above, as these would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are okay with no math, then regression and other stories is a good statistics book.

Comment: I really enjoyed Serious stats by Thom Baguley, it covers a variety of topics in statistics and is actually written in a very clear manner